# REGEXP関数で、特定の一桁の数字が含まれている場合だけマッチさせたい

Tags: mysql, 正規表現

MySQLにて次のようなパターンのものをマッチさせたい場合、どのような正規表現を書けばよいでしょうか？

6を含むもの

```
6
6,8
3,6
3,6,8
```

今のところ下記のようにやっているのですが余計なのにマッチしてしまいます。

```
 REGEXP ',?6,?'
```

マッチさせたくない余計なもの：

```
 66
```

など

Comment: 本文の説明(6)と、サンプルコードの文字(4)が食い違っていますが、どちらが正しいのでしょう?

Comment: すいません(6)が正しいです。

Comment: 後から検索した人が、タイトルだけで内容を把握しやすいよう[edit]してみました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)の単語境界の文字クラス（`[[:<:]]`、`[[:>:]]`）を用いて、下記の正規表現でマッチさせることが出来ます。

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]]6[[:>:]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

`'(^|,)6(,|$)'` でマッチさせることが出来ます。(そもそも、テーブルの設計を見直した方が良さそうですけど)